# Disable highlighting at all

Tags: dygraphs

I just would like to disable highlighting https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-series-highlighting.html on all chart series, so no legend, no circle points on series on mouse over, so no event handler...

any advice here?

so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the options `legend: "never", highlightCircleSize: 0` to disable the legend and the circles.

Comment: I think that with highlightCircleSize  = 0 event handler is still registered on point. am i right? i have a lot of points and i just would like to keep chart really light!